# regexp not catching all emails

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get emails in a php program and I am using the following regexp

```
([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b)siU
```

This appears to be working fine for getting your standard emails. Such as `me @ gmail.com` or `you @ hotmail.com`

Where this fails is on emails with ending such as co.uk. Now I have tried adding co.uk in my regexp as such

```
([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|co.uk|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b)siU
```

But that just gives me the same output as the original regexp. Where the output of the email is, you@co  . I also tried just adding in uk. What am I missing on this one? Is it the second period throwing it off?

Ideally I am trying to make it catch all emails with .com .net .org co.uk .au .ca. Basically I am searching for all US, UK, AU and CA emails. Can anyone spot what my mistake is to be able to output non US emails properly like `you @ yoursite.co.uk` instead of `you @ yoursite.co`

Thank you. The spaces in the emails shown for example are only there to get this to post.

Edit: I am not trying to validate the emails, its a series of emails that can be anything that are in an array and I am trying to only catch specific ones for a database. Sorry for not making that clear initially.

Edit2: Here is my working string for my issue. Thanks everyone

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$^
```

Comment: any reason why are you so restrictive? there are various valid mails that will not be excepted with this kind of regexp. Why not just checking that there is letters before and after @ sign?

Comment: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) contains everything you need to know about e-mail regular expressions. It solves the problem considering RFC 2822. Read it. Hope It helped.

Comment: technically speaking, YOu really shouldnt be trying to validate an email that strict. YOU wont ever keep up on all the valid TLDs (esp the HUGE list coming out now/soon/future).   Realistically, 1) check for an @, 2) split at @, 3) as long as left side is non-blank, 4) as long as right is non-blank, and has at least 1 "." -> accept it as an email -> move on with life. let your mail sender and the entire email exchange/relay system of the handle trying to send it somewhere. there are reasons sendmail failure codes exist. want to prove it was a "valid" email? send them a confirm link in a mail.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input on this I was able to solve it with the following regexp string

    ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$^

Will have to later look into other alternatives for catching the email in the array. 

Again thanks for the time and effort to help me so quickly!!

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use regex to validate email addresses. Use libraries that do it correctly.

See [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

|co.uk|

try to (not in [] , dot mean anything but break link)

```
|co\.uk|
```

Comment: That gave me the same output of @ co instead of @ co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the dot like this.

```
co\.uk
```

If you are trying to match only valid emails this regexp should do the trick

```
(\s)?(([^\s]+)\@([^\s]+))
```

Comment: Note: space can be part of a valid email, according to RFC.

Comment: But have you seen any email with space? :P

Comment: My comment is concerned about this statement: `match only valid emails`. Your regex does not match all valid emails, and sometimes include invalid ones also. `"@"`

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing on this one?

You are adding terms to a non-capturing group.  So how can any output based on your regex contain anything in a non-capturing group?  Not to mention the mistake in the term you added that nacholibre mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use regex for email, you wont like it, and you will fail.

filter_var()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Cant mark this as useful, but thanks for pointing this out. I will have to give it a good read and see if this might actually be a better solution for my program.